# Load libraries, scripts, etc for the website from external or internal sources?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started my adventure with frontend, most likely with web design. I've been struggling to answer one technical question and I couldn't find yet a reasonable answer.

There's so many libraries you can load, download to make your web developing faster. Therefore there is my question.
Is it better to download these libraries (e.g. Boostrap, jQuery, Angular, fonts from Google and so) and link to them (externally) from the official source or download it, upload to your server and  then link to the location file (internal source) on your server?

My imagination tells me that if I would download them and upload em on my server, then link to it would make the whole website load quicker. Is that a good thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pro hosting and linking to external resources** (may it be JS libraries, images or whatever):

1. Spreading the load: your server doesn't have to serve all content, it can concentrate on its main functionality and serve the application itself.
2. Spread the HTTP connections: due to more and more asynchronously working applications it is a good thing to use the maximum parallel HTTP connections per site/subdomain to deliver application data and load all necessary additional resources from other servers.
3. as Rafael mentioned above, CDNs scale very good and seldom go offline.

**Cons**

1. Even with fast internet connections there is a high chance that resources will be served faster when they are located on the same Intranet. That's why some companies have their own "Micro-CDNs" inside their local networks to combine the advantages of multiple servers and local availability.
2. External dependancy: as soon as an Internet connection becomes unavailable or a Proxy server goes down, all external resources become unavailable leaving the application in a broken state.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it may be actually faster if you link from an external source. That's because the browser stores recent data it accesses, and many sites use Bootstrap, jQuery and the such. It might not happen frequently with less popular libraries.

Keep in mind, though, since you're downloading from external sources, you're at the mercy of their servers. If for some reason or another it gets offline, your page won't work correctly. CDNs are not supposed to go offline for that very reason, but it's good to be aware of that. Also, when/if you're offline and working on your page, you won't be able to connect during development.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to download these files locally if you are developing some application for more security so that you do not really have to depend on any third party server which hosts the CDN.

Talking about performance using CDN might be beneficial because the libraries that you require might be cached in your browser so the time to fetch the file is saved. But if the file is available locally loading these files will definately take time and space.

https://halfelf.org/2015/cdn-vs-local/

https://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-not-to-use-a-cdn/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rafael's answer above, but wanted to note a few benefits of serving up these libraries locally that he or she omitted.

It is still considered best practice (until HTTP2 becomes widespread) to try to minimize the amount of downloads being made by your site by concatenating many files into a single file.  SO-- if you are using three Javascript libraries/frameworks (for instance, Angular, jQuery and Moment.js), if you are using a CDN that is three separate script elements pulling down three separate .js files.  However, if you host them locally, you can have your build process include a step where it bundles the three libraries together into a single file called "vendor.js" or something along those lines.  This has the added bonus of simplifying dependency loading to some degree, as you can concatenate them in a certain order should the need be.

Finally, although it is a little advanced if you are just getting started, if you are considering hosting your library files with your project it would definitely be worth looking into bower (https://bower.io/docs/api/) -- it is a node build tool that allows you to define what packages need to be included in your project and then install them with a single command-- particularly useful for keeping unnecessary library files out of your version control.  Good luck!